# Loop over values in multiple colums with condition and print first column value if true in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

My data is as follows (this is just a sample, real data has ~20,000 lines) :

Original raw data (tsv):

```
Names   USA EU  FR
Jim     3   12  5
John    8   4   7
Jane    12  35  3
Sue     6   3   9
```

Image of original Data:

[image: Orig data]

I want to loop over each col starting with col 2 and if values are greater than 5, then print the column 1 value of that line. The resulting data should be as follows (tab separated):

Resulting Raw Data (tsv):

```
USA   EU   FR
John  Jim  John
Jane  Jane Sue
Sue
```

Image of resulting data:

[image: Resulting data]

I have tried the following:

```
    awk -F"\t" '{ 
            for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
                if($i > 5){
                    print $1 
                } 
            }
        }' file > results
```

But it prints all the results in a single column and doesnt grab the headers of the other cols. I have also tried to capture the header during each loop step with `print FNR == i {print $1} "\n"` but I get a syntax error related to the index:

```
    awk: cmd. line:4:                 print FNR == i {print $1} "\n"
    awk: cmd. line:4:                                ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:8:     }
    awk: cmd. line:8:     ^ syntax error
```

Comment: replace the images with text so we can help you. We can't copy/paste pictures to test with.

Comment: how many rows and columns? (ie. will data comfortably fit in memory?)

Comment: Just edited to include raw data in addition to images, thanks!

Comment: The expected output you provided doesn't look as expected given the requirements you stated - `I want to loop over each col starting with col 2 and if values are greater than 5, then print the column 1 value of that line.`. Why are the "Jim" and "John" input lines condensed into 1 output line? Why are the Sue results split over 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output you provided doesn't show what you describe as your requirements so maybe this is what you really want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR > 1 {
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        $i = ( $i > 5 ? $1 : "" )
    }
}
{
    $1 = ""
    sub(OFS,"")
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
USA     EU      FR
        Jim
John            John
Jane    Jane
Sue             Sue
```

Answer (score 1):

One `GNU awk` (for multidimensional arrays) idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { for (col=2;col<=NF;col++)
            output=output (col==2 ? "" : OFS) $col
        print output
        next
      }
      { for (col=2;col<=NF;col++)
            if ($col > 5)
               names[++count[col]][col]=$1
      }
END   { for (col=2;col<=NF;col++)  
            maxlines=(count[col]>maxlines ? count[col] : maxlines)
        for (lineno=1;lineno<=maxlines;lineno++) {
            output=""
            for (col=2;col<=NF;col++)
                output=output (col==2 ? "" : OFS) names[lineno][col]
            print output
        }
      }
' file.tsv
```

This generates:

```
USA     EU      FR
John    Jim     John
Jane    Jane    Sue
Sue
```

Comment: instead of repeatedly checking whether it's `col == 2 ? .. : ..` , why not simply always pre-pend the `OFS` before the indexed item for each loop cycle, then do a `print substr(output, 2)` at the end of it ? or better yet …. in the `END` section you're not using `$0` anymore anyway, so wouldn't it be easier to concat the array elements into fields with offset of 1 (e.g. `col==2  to $1` etc), then u can even skip manual handling of OFS part, and directly `print $0`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution without needing any arrays :

```
{m,g}awk '
  BEGIN { FS=(OFS="\t")"+" 
} !_<NR { gsub(    "\t(([-][0-9]+|[+]?[0-4])([.][0-9]*)?)(\t|$)",
                    "\t_\t")
          gsub("[0-9]+", $!_) } sub("^[^\t]*\t",_)^_'


USA   EU    FR
_     Jim   Jim
John  _     John
Jane  Jane  _
Sue   _     Sue
```